# libgdx AndroidApplication class

Tags: android, libgdx

AndroidApplication class extends android activity class, then why it gives following error:

```
   06-06 05:47:17.610: E/AndroidRuntime(12567): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.badlogic.drop/com.badlogic.drop.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-06 05:47:17.610: E/AndroidRuntime(12567):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
06-06 05:47:17.610: E/AndroidRuntime(12567):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
06-06 05:47:17.610: E/AndroidRuntime(12567):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1836)
06-06 05:47:17.610: E/AndroidRuntime(12567):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
06-06 05:47:17.610: E/AndroidRuntime(12567):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
06-06 05:47:17.610: E/AndroidRuntime(12567):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-06 05:47:17.610: E/AndroidRuntime(12567):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
06-06 05:47:17.610: E/AndroidRuntime(12567):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
06-06 05:47:17.610: E/AndroidRuntime(12567):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-06 05:47:17.610: E/AndroidRuntime(12567):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
06-06 05:47:17.610: E/AndroidRuntime(12567):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
06-06 05:47:17.610: E/AndroidRuntime(12567):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
06-06 05:47:17.610: E/AndroidRuntime(12567):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-06 05:47:17.610: E/AndroidRuntime(12567): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-06 05:47:17.610: E/AndroidRuntime(12567):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.onResume(AndroidApplication.java:223)
06-06 05:47:17.610: E/AndroidRuntime(12567):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1153)
06-06 05:47:17.610: E/AndroidRuntime(12567):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4468)
06-06 05:47:17.610: E/AndroidRuntime(12567):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
```

I extended MainActivity class to AndroidApplication from Activity , then it gives above error. But when I uncomment follwing commented part, then it works perfectly.Please help to resolve it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication {


 AndroidApplication app;
 LinearLayout m3d;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

/* AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        config.useGL20 = false;
        config.useAccelerometer = false;
        config.useCompass = false;

        m3d = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.m3d);
        View m3dDrop =  initializeForView(new Drop(), config);

        m3d.addView(m3dDrop); */ 

    }


}
```

Comment: Were you able to render view into main layout as a subview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess it's because you're not calling `initializeForView()`, which needs to be called in `onCreate()`. The [documentation](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidApplication.html#initializeForView%28com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener,%20com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration%29) explains that you need all that commented code.

To resolve, just put the commented code back in. Why did you even take it out?

Comment: thanks.I'm doing it because I already have my android main class which extends Activity class.And now I want to use libgdx rendered view into this main layout as a subview. But when I extend it from  AndroidApplication, it gives me an error.

Comment: @CodeDroid I don't know. Would be interesting to try.